# More than one instance of overloaded function matches the argument list and I can't find where the error happens

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I get the above error when I use this code.

```
    //Programming Assignment 1
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Function Prototypes
void getname(ofstream);
//void Evaluate_holesterol(ofstream);
//void Evaluate_BMI(ofstream);
//void Evaluate_bloodpressure(ofstream);

int main()
{
    //Open output file
    ofstream pfile;
    pfile.open("Profile.txt");

    getname(pfile);

    //Evaluate_holesterol(pfile);

    //Evaluate_BMI(pfile);

    //Evaluate_bloodpressure(pfile);

    //pfile.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//Function to get patient's name
void getname(ofstream &pfile)
{
    string name;
    int age;

    cout<<"What is the patient's full name (middle initial included)?";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout<<endl<<"What is the patient's age?";
    cin>>age;

    string line = "Patient's Name: ";
    string ageline = "Patient's Age: ";
    pfile<<line+name<<endl;
    pfile<<age<<endl;

}
```

I've checked my functions and arguments and I don't see any function that its can be confusing its arguments with anywhere else. Apologies in advance if its something simple and I just didn't see it.

Comment: Your declaration of `getname` doesn't have a `&`, but your definition does.

Comment: Before `main()` you have a declaration `void getname(ofstream)`.  After `main()` you have a definition of `void getname(ofstream &pfile)`.    Note the missing `&` in the first.   That's the problem in your code - why it gives that specific error with your compiler, I don't know   (a `std::ofstream` cannot be passed by value, so the first declaration would not compile).

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `ofstream pfile; pfile.open(“Profile.txt”);` to `ofstream pfile(“Profile.txt”);`.

Comment: The compiler's error message tells you exactly where the error occurs. Recent compilers even tell you the name and prototypes of the conflicting overloads.

Comment: Thats very helpful thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments by cigien and Peter already pointed out: The declaration and the definition of `getname()` have mismatched parameters. To fix that, change the line

```
void getname(ofstream);
```

to

```
void getname(ofstream&);
```

Note the `&` after `ofstream`.

Furthermore, any function that gets an `ofstream` as parameter should get that by reference (i. e. as `ofstream&` and not just `ofstream`), because there is no copy constructor for `ofstream` and any attempt to pass `ofstream` by value will cause compile errors.